# Login and Registration on Index view using ViewModel in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to add a registration form and login form on the index view and show a (working) logout button (preferably just an anchor element) when logged on within my MVC project. I copied some of the existing default login code and want to add some of the existing default registration code (both found in the default `AccountController`) to my `HomeController`. My current code looks like this:

`HomeController`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Transactions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet;
using Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth;
using WebMatrix.WebData;
using Rent_a_Car.Filters;
using Rent_a_Car.Models;

namespace Rent_a_Car.Controllers
{
    [InitializeSimpleMembership]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

            return View();
        }

        // POST: /
        // I think on Post I need to decide wether the register form or login form is returned from the view
        // And make some methods that handle these forms, but I do not understand how to do this within MVC
        // This is how far I came to understand on how to add at least a login and probably should change the
        // name of the method to make it more understandable to what the code actually is supposed to do?

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Index(LoginRegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.Login.UserName, model.Login.Password, persistCookie: model.Login.RememberMe))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "De ingevulde gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord is onjuist ingevoerd.");
            return View(model);
        }

        private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
        {
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

            return View();
        }

        /*
        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
         */
    }
}
```

My `Index.cshtml` view:

```
@model Rent_a_Car.Models.LoginRegisterViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="registrate">
    <h2>Rent-a-Car</h2>
    <h4>Registreer</h4>
    <hr />
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary()

        <p>De volgende gegevens zijn nodig om een bestelling te kunnen plaatsen voor het huren van een auto:</p>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Register.UserName, new { @class = "form-control text-box single-line", @name = "E-mail", @placeholder = "E-mail" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Register.Password, new { @class = "form-control text-box single-line", @name = "Wachtwoord", @placeholder = "Wachtwoord" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Register.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control text-box single-line", @name = "Bevestig", @placeholder = "Bevestig uw wachtwoord" })
        </div>
    }
</div>

<div class="welcome">
    <h4>Log in</h4>
    <hr />
    @using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <p>Om een auto te kunnen huren moet u eerst ingelogd zijn: </p>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Login.UserName, new { @class = "form-control text-box single-line", @name = "E-mail", @placeholder = "E-mail" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Login.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Login.Password, new { @class = "form-control text-box single-line", @name = "Wachtwoord", @placeholder = "Wachtwoord" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Login.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Login.RememberMe)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Login.RememberMe)
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Inloggen" />
    }
    <hr />
    <div class="shopping-cart">
        <h4>Winkelwagen</h4>
        <hr />
        <p>U heeft de volgende auto's geselecteerd: </p>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="catalogue">
    <h3>Huur één of meerdere beschikbare auto's</h3>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="catalogue-box">
                <h4>Opel</h4>
                <hr />
                <img src="#" />
                <p>Beschrijving</p>
                <span>Prijs: zoveel euro</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="catalogue-box">
                <h4>Seat</h4>
                <hr />
                <img src="#" />
                <p>Beschrijving</p>
                <span>Prijs: zoveel euro</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="catalogue-box">
                <h4>Skoda</h4>
                <hr />
                <img src="#" />
                <p>Beschrijving</p>
                <span>Prijs: zoveel euro</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="catalogue-box">
                <h4>Volkswagen</h4>
                <hr />
                <img src="#" />
                <p>Beschrijving</p>
                <span>Prijs: zoveel euro</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="catalogue-box">
                    <h4>Mercedes</h4>
                    <hr />
                    <img src="#" />
                    <p>Beschrijving</p>
                    <span>Prijs: zoveel euro</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="catalogue-box">
                    <h4>Toyata</h4>
                    <hr />
                    <img src="#" />
                    <p>Beschrijving</p>
                    <span>Prijs: zoveel euro</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="catalogue-box">
                    <h4>Renault</h4>
                    <hr />
                    <img src="#" />
                    <p>Beschrijving</p>
                    <span>Prijs: zoveel euro</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="catalogue-box">
                    <h4>Ford</h4>
                    <hr />
                    <img src="#" />
                    <p>Beschrijving</p>
                    <span>Prijs: zoveel euro</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @* foreach logic *@
    @*
    @foreach (var car in Model)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => car.Title)
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => car.ReleaseDate)
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => car.Genre)
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => car.Price)
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = car.ID })
    }*@
</div>

@*
@section featured {
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
                <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
            </hgroup>
            <p>
                To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit
                <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
                The page features <mark>videos, tutorials, and samples</mark> to help you get the most from ASP.NET MVC.
                If you have any questions about ASP.NET MVC visit
                <a href="http://forums.asp.net/1146.aspx/1?MVC" title="ASP.NET MVC Forum">our forums</a>.
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
}
<h3>We suggest the following:</h3>
<ol class="round">
    <li class="one">
        <h5>Getting Started</h5>
        ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic websites that
        enables a clean separation of concerns and that gives you full control over markup
        for enjoyable, agile development. ASP.NET MVC includes many features that enable
        fast, TDD-friendly development for creating sophisticated applications that use
        the latest web standards.
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245151">Learn more…</a>
    </li>

    <li class="two">
        <h5>Add NuGet packages and jump-start your coding</h5>
        NuGet makes it easy to install and update free libraries and tools.
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245153">Learn more…</a>
    </li>

    <li class="three">
        <h5>Find Web Hosting</h5>
        You can easily find a web hosting company that offers the right mix of features
        and price for your applications.
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245157">Learn more…</a>
    </li>
</ol>
*@
```

Should I change the HTML helpers for both the forms to point to different methods to the forms on post?

How should I make HomeController look like to handle these two forms seperately (after clicking the login button, stay on the index view/page, but show that user is logged on. After clicking register button, show that the account has been registered, preferably for simplicty by just adding a label beneath the form which would show that message or something likewise) and how should change the `Index` method in my `HomeController` to show a logout button (e.g. in my layout view or for simplicity, `Index.cshtml` view) when a user is logged on?

Comment: Have 2 separate POST methods and specify the action and controller names in the `BeginForm` method. But why are you generating all that extra html on the index page? You could just have a `Register` and `Login` buttons that load the appropriate form using ajax.

Comment: @StephenMuecke What do you mean by "generating al that extra html"? And by changing the POST methods, do you mean changing `@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {` to  `@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {`? When I do this and change the method in my HomeController accordingly, an exception is thrown because it is trying to redirect to a Login view for some reason?

Comment: A user cannot both register and login at the same time, and they will only ever register once, and only login once per session, so why generate all that extra html. As for the error, you have not shown the controller methods so impossible to tell what you have done wrong

Comment: @StephenMuecke That is what I am trying to achieve aswell, I want to show the login form within the index view once a user is not logged on, else it should show a shopping cart instead and hide the register form when a user is logged on. I haven't changed the content of the method handling the login, but I changed to name of the method from `public ActionResult Index(LoginRegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl)` to `public ActionResult Login(LoginRegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl)`.

Comment: Rather than putting all together in a single html page, I suggest you to use separate partial views containing BeginForm method which point to specific controller and action names (login, register, etc) with Html.RenderPartial(). Render certain partial view only when an action has triggered, e.g. login form and submit button if the user is not logged in.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto So `Html.RenderPartial()` would point to a controller and handle wether it should return a certain piece of HTML Razor code found in a partial view called within the controller?

Comment: It unclear why you wanting to do this. Why are you not following the normal pattern and decorating your methods with `[Authorize]` so that is a user navigates to a page requiring authorization, they are automatically redirected to the login page (and then back to the initial page if successful)?

Comment: Because I want to keep the application to a single page, I do not wish for unnecessary steps having a user go to all kinds of pages (to reduce/prevent loading waiting time), all a user would require to do is register (retrieve personal data, so an order can be placed on his or her name) and login to show a shopping cart, so the selection of a user can be remembered.

Comment: Html.RenderPartial() just attaching your partial view in Index page, not invoking BeginForm() method (still requires a button to invoke submit action). Better using `Html.RenderAction("MethodName")` when rendering specific view depending on user's state, e.g. returning shopping cart after the user logged in: `if (!IsLoggedIn) { return PartialView("Login"); } else { return PartialView("ShoppingCart"); }`.

Comment: Then use a button to call a server method that returns a partial view of the form. And you don't have a 'single page app' (you redirect to other views). And your not improving performance - your degrading it by always including extra unnecessary html.